# Namespace of circular import

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, namespaces

When the shell  `import` module **one**, I thought the **one** will import  **two** and run the code of **two** so it will import **three** automatically. Thus, three names of the modules will all include in the `dir()`.

Actually, when I check the namespace, theres only module **one** (see below).

How it can print the `'Hello'`without including the namespace of module **two** and **three**? Since the `one.f1()` relies on both modules.

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> import one
in three
In two
in one
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'one']
>>> one.f1()
Hello
>>>
```

---

```
'one.py'
import two
print('in one')

def f1():
    two.f2()

def f4():
    print ('Hello')
```

---

```
'two.py'
import three
print ('In two')

def f2():
    three.f3()
```

---

```
'three.py'
import one
print('in three')
def f3():
    one.f4()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each module has their *own* namespace, including the main script. You only imported module `one` into the main script namespace.

The other modules are imported into the namespaces for module `one` and module `two`, respectively.

In fact, importing only really means that you created a reference to the imported items (here the module objects) in the current namespace. Python will make sure that the module is loaded first (which is when you see the `print()` statements being executed), after which the actual import takes place (the binding of names in the current namespace).

Thus, the statement `import one` does two things:

- Find and load the module `one`, *once*, if it wasn't yet loaded. This includes creating the module and inserting names into it.
- Bind the name `one` in the current namespace to the module.

Modules are stored in `sys.modules`; they are stored there the moment loading starts.

In your case, the loading of module `one` triggers another import, so Python loads module `two` to satisfy that import. That in turn triggers the import of module `three`. `three` imports `one`, a module *already present in `sys.modules`*. The name `one` thus doesn't present a problem, as there is a module to bind to already. That module is still empty (as it is still in the process of loading).

The full sequence of events is:

- `import one` -> No such module in `sys.modules`

  - Create `sys.modules['one']`, load code and start executing
  - `import two` -> No such module in `sys.modules`
  - Create `sys.modules['two']`, load code and start executing
  - `import three` -> No such module in `sys.modules`

    - Create `sys.modules['three']`, load code and start executing
    - `import one` -> `sys.modules['one']` exists, bind `one` to `sys.modules['one']`.
    - `print('in three')`
    - Create function `f3`.
    - Loading completes for `three`
  - Bind `three` to `sys.modules['three']`
  - `print ('In two')`
  - Create function `f2`
  - Loading completes for `two`
  - Bind `two` to `sys.modules['two']`
  - `print('in one')`
  - Create functions `f1` and `f4`
  - Loading completes for `one`
- Execute `one.f1()`

  - `one.f1()` exists and is executed -> `two.f2()`
  - `two.f2()` exists and is executed -> `three.f3()`

    - `three.f3()` exists and is executed -> `one.f4()`
    - `one.f4()` exists and is executed > `print('Hello')`

The fact that `one.f4()` did not *yet* exist when `three.f3()` was created doesn't matter here; the name is only looked up when the function is executed.